# Mongoose sometimes save objectId as string, some times no

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Sometimes mongoose save "main_id" as string instead of ObjectId, after save I see string type in mongoshell and UI client.

mongoose: 4.11.0

I have schema:

```
var building = new Schema({
    location: {
        main_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,  ref: 'locations'},
        title: {type: String},
        description: {type: String}
    },
    year: {type: Number}
});

var User = new Schema({    
    my_location: {
        now: building,
        more: [building]
    }
})
```

When code below runs sometimes I got string in DB instead objectId.

```
user.my_location.more[i].location.main_id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("584fe811ed936fe74d8b470e")
user.save()
```

When I check typeof `user.my_location.more[i].location.main_id` after save is says "object" but in DB show string :) and when I run query in mongoDB with ObjectId I can't found this updated document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Force tell mongoose to save something** 
*(solves the "sometimes" problem in my case)*

When I set field like value for variable mongoose checks changes for schema and update only them (as I understood from docs) but mongoose don't check nested arrays for changes.

So we have two native tricks:

1. Force tell mongoose which field was modified

   `user.markModified('my_location.more')
   user.save() //Now all good`
2. Change array element values via `set`

   `user.my_location.more[i].location.main_id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("584fe811ed936fe74d8b470e")
   user.my_location.more[i].year = 2019
   user.my_location.set(i, user.my_location.more) //To set whole changed object
   user.save()`